# Odd Results from Arm IT LT Instruction

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cortex-m, iar

I have the following C code in the generated assembly listing:

```
//  359     // File must contain at least the Base64 SHA-1/HMAC
//  360     if (m_fileLength < AsciiSignatureLength)
        LDR      R0,[R6, #+8]
        CMP      R0,#+40
        IT       LT 
//  361     {
//  362         retVal = InvalidCrc;
        MOVLT    R5,#+2
        BLT.N    ??readSignatureNC_2
//  363     }
```

This is running on an ARM Cortex M3 (STM32f1xx) and the IAR Compiler with High optimization settings. Coming into this function the value of m_fileLength is 55, and AsciiSignatureLength is a const 40.
According to the debugger R0 is correctly getting the value 55. The CMP is correctly setting the APSR register flags, but for some reason when the IT LT command executes it is dumping into the "then clause", causing retval to be equal to InvalidCRC.

This same c code when compiled with no optimizations generates a cmp followed by a BNEQ assembly that works exactly as expected.

I have looked around for an erata relating to the IT LT command in the stm32 and didn't find anything, nor does it seem like the IAR compiler is generating "bad" assembly for the given c code unless I misunderstand something here.
Thanks, Josh

Comment: You write 'when the IT LT command executes it is dumping into the "then clause",causing retval to be equal to InvalidCRC.'. Are you SURE that retval is wrong? It is perfectly normal that you see the cpu running through that code in the debugger, IT does not generate branches, but only prevents the following instruction from being executed, it will still be fetched etc.

Comment: Is `R5` set to *2*?  Ie, `InvalidCRC` is the constant *2*?  Is `R0` also 55, when you get here?  I guess `R6` is the `this` pointer and `m_fileLength` is the 2nd member.  Masta is right that the code will always execute this branch.  However `movlt r5,#2` will be a *nop* or it will set `r5` to 2 depending on the conditions.  As well, you may have an OS issue where the CPSR (or what ever the Cortex-M calls it) is not saved/restored correctly if you have multi-tasking; `IT` state is stored there.

Comment: @Masta79 Yes I'm sure the next line (then clause) is executing; retVal is defintely getting the wrong value.

Comment: @artlessnoise `R5` is getting set to 2 yes and `R0` is definitely 55.

Comment: @JoshPatterson: Then this would be a enormous hardware-bug, which I just can't believe. Constructs like these are very common in compiled code, if this would be broken your device most probably would never ever reach this code at all.

Comment: It could be an OS or debugger issue with saving/restoring the `IT` state.  This is stored in a *status register*.  As two task maybe doing conditionals *simultaneous* (or during a reschedule), then the `IT` state must be properly extracted and restored during the context switch.  However, we don't know what OS is running (or the debugger single step functionality).

Comment: does it happen all the time or now and then? and it is not due to a signed integer overflow etc?

Comment: @auselen it happens every time (well this is in a unit test so every time its the same);

Comment: @Masta79 as best I can tell the IT block is never used by IAR unless some form of optimizations are turned on.

Comment: @artlessnoise It could be related to saving/restoring IT state that is an interesting possibility, though if that were the problem I'd think it would be more intermittent.

Comment: then try to reproduce a more confined example, so at worst you can issue a bug report.

Comment: Now this only happens when you are debugging and single stepping or also when running normally?

Comment: This it lt movlt blt works fine for me on a nxp cortex-m3 (mbed), an stm32f1xxx cortex-m3 (value line discovery), and a ti cortex-m4 (launchpad), running normally (not single stepping or anything like that).